# Cannot able to control div under POPUP window when the window is maximized

Tags: css

I am opening a popup window (inside it there is a `div` for displaying the chart)
When the maximize button is pressed the components are not aligned properly.

So for this i have read that we also need to have a `parent` container to solve the issue.

So i kept this way :

```
<div id="parent" style="margin:0 auto; width:1000px; position:relative;">

   <div id= "finance" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px;"></div>

</div>
```

As a result of this , I am not able to increase the width of the div.

Please see the image [here](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=0280b8e)

My CSS is this

```
.centered {
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
}
.html{ width:100%; height:100%; }
.body{ width:100%; height:100%; }
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

CSS Experts please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yor are referencing to `.centered` in your CSS and there's no centered class in any div. Plus, `style` attributes have more relevance in the result than classes or even ids, so no matter what you put in your css, the div `parent` will always be `1000px`.

Also, you didn't say if you need the div to grow with the window, or just to be centered when the window is maximized.

You need to get rid of all the style attributes and reffer to those divs with their id's in the css:

```
#parent {
    width: 1000px; /* or percentage if you want it to grow */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#finance {
    margin: 10px;
}
```